# c# BackgroundWorker DoWork method calling another class and ProgressReport

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am running a BackgroundWorker thread to do a time consuming task.  The time consuming task is in another class.  I need to pass the progress being made on this separate class running on BackgroundWorker back to the Main Form1 class.  I am not sure how to approach this.  Please provide suggestions.  Thank you in advance.

```
    **// Main Form1 UI Class**    

    public void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Argument always contains whatever was sent to the background worker
        // in RunWorkerAsync. We can simply cast it to its original type.
        DataSet ds = e.Argument as DataSet;
        this.createje.ProcessData(this.ds);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = CreateJE.max;
        this.progressBar1.Value = e.Recno;
    }

    **//Other Class called CreateJE**

    public void ProcessData(DataSet ds)
    {
        //Do time consuming task...
     for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                **//How do I report progress back to the Main UI?** 
                //worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest, and most extendable, solution is probably to have your `ProcessData()` method raise an event, which the `BackgroundWorker` is listening for. This way `ProcessData()` doesn't depend on having a `BackgroundWorker` as a caller. (You would also need to make a way of canceling out of `ProcessData()`). You can even re-use the `ProgressChangedEventArgs` if you want. For example (not tested but you get the idea?):

```
partial class Form1 { 
    public void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        //e.Argument always contains whatever was sent to the background worker 
        // in RunWorkerAsync. We can simply cast it to its original type.
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)e.Argument;
        var bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

        var eh = new ProgressChangedEventHandler((o,a) => bgw.ReportProgress(a.ProgressPercentage));
        createje.ProgressChanged += eh;
        this.createje.ProcessData(this.ds));
        createje.ProgressChanged -= eh; //necessary to stop listening
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = CreateJE.max;
        this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

}

partial class CreateJE { 

    public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged; 
    protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        var hand = ProgressChanged; 
        if(hand != null) hand(this, e);
    }

    public void ProcessData(DataSet ds)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            var e = new ProgressChangedEventArgs(i * 10, null);
        }
    }

}
```

The quick and dirty way is to just pass the `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter to `ProcessData()`. This is IMHO rather ugly, though, ties you down to using only BackgroundWorkers, and also forces you to define the `BackgroundWorker` in one place (the main form class) and the returned values of ReportProgress in another (the CreateJE class).

You could also use a timer and report back progress every X ms, querying the CreateJE object for its progress. This seems in-line with the rest of your code. The hangup with this is it would make your CreateJE class not multi-thread-friendly.

Comment: I like your first suggestion.  Can you supply a code example?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and simplest option would be to declare a `delegate`in class `CreateJE` that will report proggress and then hook this to the `ReportProgress` method of `BackgroundWorker`.

```
class CreateJE
{
    public Action<int> ReportProgressDelegate{get;set;}

    public void ProcessData(DataSet ds)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            ReportProgress(i*10);
        }
    }

    private void ReportProgress(int percent)
    {
        if(ReportProgressDelegate != null)
            ReportProgressDelegate(percent);
    }
}
```

In your form, initialize `ReportProgressDelegate` property of your instance (I assume `this.createje` refers to a field of the form so `OnLoad` seems like a good place to do the initialization):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.creatje.ReportProgressDelegate = worker.ReportProgress;
}
```

After that, you can use the event handlers you already have (`backgroundWorker2_DoWork` and `backgroundWorker2_DoWork`).

**PS**: You should use the same approach with `worker.CancellationPending` property.